# The provisioning profile iOS team is expiring soon (free account)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

The first time I deployed an app to an iPhone I got this warning. When you Google for answers it seems like I should go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate and refresh my provisioning profile. However, I can't access that page and just gets redirected to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome.

I REALLY hate to have this warning and it seems that there is no way to remove it. Does anyone know hot to fix this for free accounts (just logging in with Apple ID)?

Comment: You ought to purchase an account and create dev certificate and provisioning profile. After logging in to your account, you will be able to access the [link you get as answer](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate). Wouldn't know about Free provisioning profile tho.

Comment: You are supposed to be able to develop apps without a payed account. I'm just asking for how to fix this warning, why down vote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't allow management of apps, certs or bundle ids without a paid account. However, a correctly-functioning, free account should let Xcode auto-create provisioning profiles which expire in about a week.  And because  they timeout so soon, this causes Xcode to nag you with a warning in order to support Apple (e.g., spending more money) to pay for the privilege of usable development, which is reasonable. Just ignore it or [spend $99 USD](https://developer.apple.com/account/) if you feel it necessary to silence this, deploy apps you wrote for longer than 1 week, deploy apps to other people's devices and perhaps publish a great app which can make you some $ too.

Comment: I have developed some Android apps for my personal use (retrieve data from some public web sites, but distributing them may violate their IP) and running them on my own Android devices. When I heard that Apple finally allowed developers to run iOS apps on their device without payment, I expected the same. But it seems that I was wrong. So, if I create some iOS apps for my personal use, I still would need to pay Apple and list them on the App Store, just to run them on my own iOS device? I see no justification for this.

Comment: You don't need to list them on the App Store—with a paid account, the certificates last much longer (something like a year, I think).

Comment: @seaturtle A Free developer app lasts 1 week. If a developer wants people to try out a beta app by using TestFlight or have a private alpha app load over USB, a developer subscription seems unavoidable. Yes, it sucks.